# postgresql: cannot run inside a transaction block

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run these commands together in `SQLbox` of `phppgadmin`

```
CREATE DATABASE "ir-staging";
CREATE USER django WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'django';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "ir-staging" TO django;
```

I get

```
SQL error:

ERROR:  CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block
In statement:
CREATE DATABASE "ir-staging";
CREATE USER django WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'django';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "ir-staging" TO django
```

Whereas if I run the

```
CREATE DATABASE "ir-staging";
```

alone it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straight forward:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html

> CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed inside a transaction block.

From the looks of it `Sqlbox` is starting a transaction with `BEGIN;` when running multiple statements and tripping the error. Whereas for single transaction it is running in autocommit mode. Look in the docs to see if you can specify autocommit as default action. Or better yet use `psql` instead.